# Generator of all congruence classes

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups, definition

Is it possible for $\langle a \rangle =\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z^*$ for $a\in  \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z^*$?

I think I recall hearing it is, what is the name this element takes? I remember hearing generator but i'm not sure.

Comment: It's possible. $\mathbb{Z}/(n)^\ast$ is cyclic iff $n \in \{2,4\}$, $n$ is a power of an odd prime, or twice the power of an odd prime. Such an element is indeed called a generator of the group, for the group of units modulo $n$ it is also called a primitive root (of unity) modulo $n$.

Comment: ill take this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an $a$ is a generator of the multiplicative group modulo $n$, and is called a [primitive root modulo $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n). They don't exist for all $n$, but they do always exist when $n$ is a prime number.